# JBoss 7 and Camel 2.11 - BeanManager complaining about "non-portable behaviour"

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, apache-camel, cdi

I'm using camel 2.11-SNAPSHOT in an ear which is running on JBoss AS 7.1.

When deploying the app and while the routes are being constucted (in a `@Singleton` `@Startup` bean, using an `@Inject`ed CdiCamelContext) i get a lot of warnings (ca. 30) like this in my server log:

```
2013-03-20 16:40:55,153 WARNING [org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.provider.BeanManagerProvider] (MSC service thread 1-2) When using the BeanManager to retrieve Beans before the Container is started, non-portable behaviour results!
```

and after the the context has been started i get this WARNINGs:

```
2013-03-20 16:40:56,339 WARNING [org.apache.deltaspike.core.api.provider.BeanManagerProvider] (Camel (camel-2) thread #1 - file:///tmp/exchange/tmobile/in) When using the BeanManager to retrieve Beans before the Container is started, non-portable behaviour results!
```

What does it mean? I couldn't find anything useful on google. Is it a bug? Did i configure camel wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a warning from Apache Deltaspike that the bean manager was accessed before the container was booted. It seems Camel's integration with CDI uses some non-portable features, but assuming that they know what they're doing, it could be nothing.

Comment: That's what i assumed so far. But can someone confirm this?